# Logitech Options doesnt have Copy and Paste options for MX Master 2s Mouse on MacOS

Tags: macos, mac, mouse, logitech-mouse

[image: Screenshot]

I have a MX Master 2s Logitech Mouse and recently migrated from windows to Mac. In Windows I can setup the additional buttons on Mx Master 2s to work as Copy and Paste through Logi Options Software, but on MacOS the Logi Options doesnt allow me to map the mouse buttons to correspond to Copy and Paste (as you can see in the screenshot, it doesnt have options for that as it has on Windows).

Is there any workaround or a different software to map Copy and Paste for the Master MX 2s additional buttons on MacOS?

Comment: Are you trying to map both commands to a single button; or two buttons, one for each command?

Comment: two buttons, one for each command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use 'Keystroke Assignment'

In this case, I've got  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>W</kbd>  for Close Window, but you can set anything you like, including
 <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  [Copy] &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd>  [Paste]

[image]

Comment: Very helpful, thanks! Still curious why it doesn't have Copy and Paste listed explicitly, like it does in Windows.

Comment: No idea. I've never seen it on Windows - might even be a different team that makes each version. It's simple enough to do anyway.